# Hazelcast MapStore's store() method is not getting invoked on map.put() operation, in client/server mode, but it works perfectly in embedded mode

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have implement HZ IMap and MapStore to store in MongoDB, by using WRITE-THROUGH strategy, but when, i make map.put() operation call, ideally it should invoke MapStores store method to save object in DB. But it isn't working in client / server implementation mode, where as it works perfectly in embedded implementation mode. can any one help me what went wrong.

Hazelcast configuration as below:

```
@Configuration
```

public class HazelcastConfiguration {

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HazelcastConfiguration.class);

@Value("${server.hazelcast.group.name:dev}")
private String groupName;

@Value("${server.hazelcast.group.password:dev}")
private String groupPassword;

@Value("${hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds:50}")
private Integer mergeFirstRunDelay;

@Value("${hazelcast.merge.next.run.delay.seconds:50}")
private Integer mergeNextRunDelay;

@Value("${hazelcast.localAddress:127.0.0.1}")
private String localAddress;

@Value("${hazelcast.jmx:true}")
private Boolean enableJMX;

@Value("${hazelcast.jmx.detailed:false}")
private Boolean enableJMXDetailed;

@Value("${server.hazelcast.network.port:5701}")
private Integer port;

@Value("${server.hazelcast.network.port-auto-increment:false}")
private Boolean portAutoIncrement;

@Value("${server.hazelcast.base.ip:}")
private String membersBaseIP;

@Value("${server.hazelcast.network.interface.ip:}")
private String networkInterfaceIP;

@Value("${MONGO_CONN_URI_APPSDB:mongodb://${MONGO_HOST:localhost}:${MONGO_PORT:27017}" +
        "/${MONGO_APP_DBNAME:spring-database}}")
private String mongoConnectionURIAppsDB;

@Value("#{ T(java.lang.Integer).valueOf('${com.eis.shiro.sessionmanager.globalsessiontimeout.millis:7200000}') / " +
        "1000 }")
private Integer globalSessionTimeout;

@Value("#{ T(java.lang.Integer).valueOf('${com.eis.sso.saml.sp.requeststate.timeout.millis:3600000}') / " +
        "1000 }")
private Integer spRequestStateTimeout;

@Value("#{ T(java.lang.Integer).valueOf('${com.eis.sso.saml.sp.responsestate.timeout.millis:3600000}') / " +
        "1000 }")
private Integer spResponseStateTimeout;

@Value("${hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds:300}")
private Integer maxNoHeartbeatSecs;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("mongoTemplate")
protected MongoTemplate mongoOps;

@Bean
public Config config() throws UnknownHostException {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.getGroupConfig().setName(groupName).setPassword(groupPassword);
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds", String.valueOf(mergeFirstRunDelay));
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.merge.next.run.delay.seconds", String.valueOf(mergeNextRunDelay));
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.localAddress", localAddress);
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.jmx", BooleanUtils.toStringTrueFalse(enableJMX));
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.jmx.detailed", BooleanUtils.toStringTrueFalse(enableJMXDetailed));
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds", String.valueOf(maxNoHeartbeatSecs));
    // no need for configuration here
    // config.setProperty("hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled", BooleanUtils.toStringTrueFalse(false));

    NetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();
    networkConfig.setPort(port);
    networkConfig.setPortAutoIncrement(portAutoIncrement);
    networkConfig.getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(networkInterfaceIP)) {
        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOG.info("Network Interfaces IP: {}", networkInterfaceIP);
        }
        networkConfig.getInterfaces().setEnabled(true);
        networkConfig.getInterfaces().addInterface(networkInterfaceIP);
    }

    networkConfig.getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(membersBaseIP)) {
        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOG.info("Member Base IP: {}", membersBaseIP);
        }
        networkConfig.getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().getMembers().add(membersBaseIP);
    }


    config.addMapConfig(getCorrelationMapConfig());
    return config;
}



private MapConfig getCorrelationMapConfig(){


    MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig("correlationMap");
    MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = new MapStoreConfig();
    mapStoreConfig.setEnabled(true);
    mapStoreConfig.setWriteDelaySeconds(0);
    mapStoreConfig.setInitialLoadMode(MapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode.LAZY);
    mapStoreConfig.setClassName(CorrelationMapStore.class.getCanonicalName());
    mapConfig.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreConfig);

    EvictionConfig evictionConfig = new EvictionConfig()
            .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
            .setMaximumSizePolicy(EvictionConfig.DEFAULT_MAX_SIZE_POLICY)
            .setSize(5000);
    NearCacheConfig nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig()
            .setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.BINARY)
            .setInvalidateOnChange(true)
            .setTimeToLiveSeconds(0)
            .setEvictionConfig(evictionConfig);

    mapConfig.setNearCacheConfig(nearCacheConfig);
    return mapConfig;
}
```

}

===============
Hazelcast-client-context xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.2.xsd" profile="hazelcast-client">

    <hz:client id="hzclient" lazy-init="false">
        <hz:group name="${client.hazelcast.group.name:dev}" password="${client.hazelcast.group.password:dev}" />
        <!-- retry for 3 hours -->
        <hz:network connection-attempt-limit="5400"
                    connection-attempt-period="2000"
                    connection-timeout="1000"
                    redo-operation="true"
                    smart-routing="true">
            <hz:member>${client.hazelcast.member.ip.1:127.0.0.1}:${client.hazelcast.member.port.1:5701}</hz:member>
            <hz:member>${client.hazelcast.member.ip.2:127.0.0.1}:${client.hazelcast.member.port.2:5701}</hz:member>
            <hz:member>${client.hazelcast.member.ip.3:127.0.0.1}:${client.hazelcast.member.port.3:5701}</hz:member>
        </hz:network>
        <hz:near-cache name="correlationMap" in-memory-format="BINARY" invalidate-on-change="true" time-to-live-seconds="0" cache-local-entries="false" eviction-policy="LRU" max-size="0"/>
    </hz:client>

    <hz:map instance-ref="hzclient" id="correlationMap" name="correlationMap" lazy-init="true" />

</beans>
```

==================================

MapStore Implementation as below:

```
public class CorrelationMapStore implements MapStore<String, Correlation> {

private static CorrelationDAO correlationDAO;

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorrelationMapStore.class);

@Override
public void store(String s, Correlation correlation) {
    refreshDAOBean();
    if (correlationDAO != null) {
        try {
            correlationDAO.save(correlation);
        } catch (B2BTransactionFailed | B2BNotFoundException | ValidationException e) {
            if (LOG.isErrorEnabled()) {
                LOG.error("Failed to save correlation for refName : {}, dataDomain : {}",
                        correlation.getRefName(), correlation.getDataDomain());
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void storeAll(Map<String, Correlation> map) {
    if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(map)) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Correlation> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey() != null) {
                store(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void delete(String s) {
    refreshDAOBean();
    if (correlationDAO != null) {
        Correlation correlation = load(s);
        if (correlation != null) {
            try {
                correlationDAO.delete(correlation);
            } catch (ValidationException | B2BTransactionFailed e) {
                if (LOG.isErrorEnabled()) {
                    LOG.error("Failed to delete correlation for refName : {}, dataDomain : {}",
                            correlation.getRefName(), correlation.getDataDomain());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void deleteAll(Collection<String> collection) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(collection)) {
        for (String correlationKey : collection) {
            delete(correlationKey);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Correlation load(String correlationKey) {
    refreshDAOBean();
    if (correlationDAO != null && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(correlationKey)) {

        try {
            return correlationDAO.getCorrelationByHierarchy(correlationKey, Constants.B2BMAILBOX_APP_DATADOMAIN);
        } catch (B2BTransactionFailed b2BTransactionFailed) {
            if (LOG.isErrorEnabled()) {
                LOG.error("Failed to get correlation for key : {}, due to {}", correlationKey,
                        b2BTransactionFailed);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Map<String, Correlation> loadAll(Collection<String> collection) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Iterable<String> loadAllKeys() {
    return null;
}

private static void refreshDAOBean() {
    try {

        if (correlationDAO == null) {
            correlationDAO = SpringApplicationContext.getBean(CorrelationDAO.class);
        }
        //CHECKSTYLE:OFF
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (LOG.isErrorEnabled()) {
            LOG.error("Error while getting Correlation DAO bean from context", e);
        }
    }//CHECKSTYLE:ON
}
```

}

Comment: Hazelcast configuration as below:

Comment: Try writing from both clientside and serverside in the same project (you can mix both at once). This will help isolate which side the fault lies. It's also worth adding temporary logging as the first line of `store(K, V)` (before `refreshDAOBean();`) as this will help confirm if it's being called and silently failing, or not being called. Also if you're really using HZ 3.2 (as the XML suggests) then it's many years old and worth upgrading.

Comment: Any updates on this ? Did the logging help clarify ?